# Why the ajax call is not working properly with same url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There are two ajax calls with same url not working properly?

```
var ss=35;
function t()
{
$.ajax({type:"POST",
          url:"BillServlet",
          data1:{message1:ss},                                                                 
          success:function(data1){
          alert('success'+data1.message1)
          }});} //this function returns null

function test()
{
$.ajax({type:"POST",
          url:"BillServlet",
          data:{message:total},                                                                 
          success:function(data){
          alert('success'+data.message)
          }});}//this function returns value
```

Why one function returns null value?

Comment: alert('success'+data)

Comment: on function t() it should be success'+data1.message rather than data1.message1

Comment: which is returning `null` and what is the value of `total`

Comment: It's `data: ...` not `data1: ...` (in `function t()`)

Comment: i think  data1:{message1:ss}, should  data:{message1:ss}, in first function

Comment: @mohit----why we use only data always?cant we use other names to it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to get the same data back from the server in both functions, in `function t()` you should change `data1.message1` to `data1.message`.

Otherwise, try printing out the value of `data1` to see what data the server is actually giving you. If you can't use `console.log(data1)` for some reason, you could also use `alert(JSON.stringify(data1))`

Answer (score 0):

Check in the firbug, are you getting the response from server? I think you are getting the blank response from server. If you are getting the response then check the indexes in the response that is it same you are alerting.